# C# System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo EnvironmentVariables being case-insensitive?

Tags: c#, variables, process, environment

The EnvironmentVariables in ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables (type `StringDictionary`) are always set to lower-case when I insert something into it. For example:

```
proc.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Clear();
proc.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("REDIRECT_STATUS", "");
// [snipped more variables being added here]
proc.Start();
```

In the process there now is a `redirect_status`, and not a `REDIRECT_STATUS` as I wanted. This causes problems.

I already read somewhere else that you could get around this issue by making a batch file, however this is not applicable in my case, as this is meant to be used as CGI (this code could potentially be called 10 times a second.)

Is there a way to get the `EnvironmentVariables` to not be case insensitive, and just allow me to go all-caps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, note to everybody out there who's also having this problem: Apparantly, this is [a bug in .Net 3.5](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/326163/processstartinfo-environmentvariables-looses-defined-case-of-environment-variables) and is fixed in 4.0.

I had to switch to .Net 4.0 to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables in Windows are case insensitive. The behavior of this variable is clearly based on that fact. If you are using environment variables in a Windows environment, this shouldn't cause trouble. You don't mention what platform this is on - is it a Mono application running on a Unix-like system?

Comment: This is a Windows Application, however, the application I am calling is PHP's CGI, where if you request $_SERVER['SOMETHING'], it is case-sensitive.

Comment: Do you have control over the PHP script? If so, replacing $_SERVER['FOO'] with getenv('FOO') should work, if the comments at http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php are correct.

Comment: I want all sorts of scripts to work, so it needs the Environment variables in upper caps. Thanks for the getenv tip, though. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and found this question. Not wanting to upgrade the project to .Net 4 at this point, I found the following workaround. This workaround depends on the internal implementation of the StringDictionary class, and doing so is often considered bad practice, but it gets the job done on .Net 2...

```
System.Reflection.FieldInfo contentsField = typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary).GetField("contents", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
System.Collections.Hashtable envtable = (System.Collections.Hashtable)contentsField.GetValue(proc.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables);
envtable.Add("REDIRECT_STATUS", "");
```

Comment: Great answer if you can't upgrade to .Net 4. The answer for me was upgrading, but you get my upvote regardless. Nice!